# Problem with the scraped Bulgarian language text in excel using bs4

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

1. I am trying to **scrape** a website that contains Bulgarian text. It is **scraped** successfully but when I store it into a CSV file it is not readable. Please see the following code and image to understand better my problem.

   ```
    res = requests.get('https://m.mobile.bg/results? 
    pubtype=1&marka=Toyota&currency=%D0%BB%D0%B2.&sort=1&nup=0~1')

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
    file = open('cars.csv', 'w')
    writer = csv.writer(file)

    # write title row
    writer.writerow(['Car_Make', 'Price', 'info', 'date'])
    for i in soup.select('.listItem'):


    car_make = i.find('div', attrs = {"class":"title"})

    arr = i.text
    print(arr)

    writer.writerow([arr.encode('utf-8')])

    file.close()
   ```

[The output in jupyter notebook is as follows. I want this to be stored as it is in csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEwxI.png)

[This is how the output looks like in a CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yj7Ag.png)

Comment: try with utf-8-sig assuming supported

Comment: utf-8-sig did not solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, @barny. I wasn't aware of terminologies since it was my first time doing such a task. Thanks for clearing the terminologies.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main(url):
    params = {
        "pubtype": "1",
        "marka": "Toyota",
        "currency": "лв.",
        "sort": "1",
        "nup": "0~1"
    }
    r = requests.get(url, params=params)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    with open('d.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows([list(x.strings)
                          for x in soup.select('.listItem.TOPitem')])


main('https://m.mobile.bg/results')
```

Output:

[image]